# Optimization results different when running script on Matlab 2016b vs 2017b

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraint-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I have a constrained optimization problem that I attempt to solve in Matlab.

- I find however that when I run the solver with Matlab `2016b` the results are different than when I run it on a different computer with Matlab `2017b`.
- I find it weird that using the non-stochastic optimizer `sqp` the solver does not converge to the same values. In fact, `2016b` does not reach a feasible point whereas `2017b` finds a local minimum.
- I have confirmed with 100% certainty that the inputs to the function below are exact the same.
- I have also tried to fix the seed (to Twister).

Where do these differences come from? How can I check what it is different in 2016b vs 2017? I did not find anything on `fmincon` in the [release notes](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=&startrelease=R2016b&endrelease=R2017b&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=).

Or is the difference coming from something different? What can I do to check and understand this?

---

Here is the core function:

```
function customOptimization(ymu, Sigma, upperTarget, maxWeight)
% ymu: 1 x M vector
% Sigma: M x M matrix
% upperTarget: double constant
% maxWeight: double constant

options = optimoptions(...
    'fmincon','Algorithm','sqp',...
    'MaxFunctionEvaluations',1e+5,'MaxIterations',1e+5, ...
    'OptimalityTolerance',1e-12,'ConstraintTolerance',1e-12, ...
    'StepTolerance',1e-6, ...
    'Display', 'off');

% Problem definition
fnhandle                 = @(x)in_objectfun(x, ymu);
nonlcon                  = @(x)in_nonlconstr(x, Sigma);
[A, b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub] =     in_linconstr(ymu);
x0                       =     in_startvalue(ymu, Sigma);

% Optimization & scaling
    [weights,fval,exitflag,output] = fmincon(fnhandle, x0, A, b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub, nonlcon, options); 


% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
% CONSTRAINTS AND OTHER

% objective function
    function  f = in_objectfun(w, imu)

        f = abs(imu) * log(abs(w))';
        f = -f;

    end

% linear constraints
    function [A, b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub] = in_linconstr(imu)

        temp = ones(0,nbAssets);
        temp(imu >= 0) = -1;
        temp(imu < 0) = 1;

        % (b) and (c)
        % Ax <= b
        A = diag(temp);
        b = zeros(nbAssets,1);

        % other
        Aeq = [];
        beq = [];
        lb = [];
        ub = [];

    end

% nonlinear constraints
    function [c,ceq] = in_nonlconstr(w, S)

        % (a)
        c(1) = sqrt(w*S*w') - upperTarget;
        c(2) = max(abs(w))/sum(abs(w)) - maxWeight;

        % (d)
        ceq = [];

    end

% starting values
    function x0 = in_startvalue(imu)

        x0 = imu/2;

    end

end
```

Comment: Probably because of the difference in the `default value` of options for which value is not set in `optimoptions`.

Comment: Default value? Starting values? Note that I am running EXACTLY the same code. No differences in default values or properties in the code.

Comment: You haven't set all the options inside `optimoptions`. Default values are set by matlab for the options not specified in  `optimoptions`. Default values may vary from version to version.

Comment: You can find the default values for 2017 here https://in.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#busog7r-options

Comment: Compare the values marked as `(default)` in both version.

Comment: Good point. I just checked and I have exactly the same in both versions. So it must be something else..?

Comment: I noted abs() in the model. That is non-differentiable and violates the assumptions of the sqp method.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Interesting... do you have a source for that?

Comment: Try adding `rng(0, 'twister')` in the begining

Comment: Any book on NLP will do. All these methods require smooth functions (continuous differentiable). So we typically reformulate `abs`. Also the `sqrt` can be removed. Proper formulation of NLP problems is quite important. Anyway, this is not related to you question.

Comment: Still useful to know... reformulating maybe will help my optimizer to reach a better solution. @ErwinKalvelagen

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I've opened a new question on this matter: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694010/how-to-reformulate-an-objective-function-with-absolute

Comment: I tried to set the seed but it did not work. Is it possible that there is something because of the version or computer?